# F# measure unit : from radians to velocity in m/s

Tags: f#, measure

let's say I've defined an F# module for handling 3-dimensional vectors and measure unit:

```
[<Measure>]
type m
[<Measure>]
type s
[<Measure>]
type v = m/s
[<Measure>]
type rad

type Vector3<[<Measure>] 'a> =
    {
    X : float<'a>
    Y : float<'a>
    Z : float<'a>
    }
```

And somewhere I have an angle expressed in radians:

```
let angle:float32<rad> = 0.5f<rad>
```

Now I have to declare a Vector3 (velocity) using the angle to calculate its components. I tried something like :

```
let velocity : Vector3<m/s> = { X = Math.Cos(angle);Y = Math.Sin(angle);Z = 0.0<m/s>} //don't compile
```

The code above doesn't compile because Vector3 is expecting a  value in X and Y but Sin returns a float.

How can I solve this problem? If it possible I would like to perform a conversion between measure units, instead of a cast, in such a way that the compiler can guarantee that I'm doing the right thing while transforming an angle into a velocity.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems here:
`cos` is expecting a unitless value, so you have to take the units off `angle`; given that velocity is expecting `float` and not `float32`, you might as well just convert directly to `float` (which removes the units).

Then, you need to put the units back on. In first versions of units of measure, you could do this by simply multiplying by 1 in the appropriate measure. Now there is `LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure`, which is more correct, but slightly more verbose.

```
let velocity =
 {
     X = angle |> float |> cos |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<m/s> ;
     Y = angle |> float |> sin |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<m/s> ;
     Z = 0.0<m/s> ;
 }
```

That aside, 10 radians is a funny angle...

*(Note that `cos` and `sin` are built-in)*

Answer (score 1):

> If it possible I would like to perform a conversion between measure
>   units, instead of a cast, in such a way that the compiler can
>   guarantee that I'm doing the right thing while transforming an angle
>   into a velocity.

You ask for contradictory things. Unit of Measure helps to guarantee correctness of programs by using type inference to enforce units in the programs, so conversion has to be done explicitly.

As @Benjol said, you have to convert between dimensional and dimensionless data. Below code is a informal version where I convert from `float` to `float<m/s>` by multiplying with its unit value:

```
let angle:float32<rad> = 0.5f<rad>

let velocity = {
                X = sin (float angle) * 1.0<m/s> ; 
                Y = cos (float angle) * 1.0<_> ; 
                Z = 0.0<_>
               }
```

Note that you only have to specify unit for X, other units are inferred based on type declaration of `Vector3`.

Comment: @Heisenbug, yes, as pad points out, your units aren't really guaranteeing you anything in this case. There is no *logical* progression here from radians to m/s...

Comment: @Benjol: yes, I understand that. But my question was also about that: is there anyway to guarantee the logical progression from radians to m/s ?

Comment: @Heisenbug, well there would be if you had a pre-existing scalar speed which you wanted to convert to a vector with the given direction.

Comment: @Benjol: do you mind posting an example? Sorry but I still have a lot of difficulties with F#..

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's another take, demonstrating how you could combine a scalar speed and a 2d-direction to really make use of your units:

```
let vvector (velocity:float<'u>) (xydirection:float<rad>) =
    { 
        X = cos (float xydirection) * velocity;
        Y = sin (float xydirection) * velocity;
        Z = 0.<_>
    }
```

Which gives:

```
> vvector 15.3<m/s> angle<rad>;;
val it : Vector3<m/s> = {X = 13.4270132;
                         Y = 7.335210741;
                         Z = 0.0;}
```

You could take it a step further by adding an operator to your Vector3 type:

```
static member (*) (v1: Vector3<'u>, n: float<'v>) =
    { X = v1.X * n; Y = v1.Y * n; Z = v1.Z * n }
```

Which would mean you could then do this:

```
let vvector2 (velocity:float<'u>) (xydirection:float<rad>) =
    { X = cos(float xydirection); Y = sin(float xydirection); Z = 0. } * velocity
```

Obviously, you're still not really 'using' your radians in there, but that's sort of expected, radians are sort of 'non' units anyway. One way that you *could* make use of them is if you wanted to be able to manage radians *and* degrees. You could add two other static members on your Vector3:

```
static member ofAngle (ang:float<rad>) = 
    { X = cos(float ang); Y = sin(float ang); Z = 0.0 }
static member ofAngle (ang:float<degree>) = 
    Vector3<'u>.ofAngle(ang * 2.<rad> * System.Math.PI / 360.<degree>)
```

That looks nice, but unfortunately it won't compile because `The method 'ofAngle' has the same name and signature as another method in this type once tuples, functions and/or units of measure are erased.` You can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666311/pattern-matching-of-units-of-measure-in-f) for more details

Comment: For your last example, you could use non-overloaded static members instead, like `ofRadianAngle` and `ofDegreeAngle` (and make them let-bound values in a module, which would probably be more idiomatic).